# Operator to remove previous element from collection in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have following list:

```
val headersAndContent = mutableListOf(..., Pair(1, "header"), Pair(2, "header"), Pair(3, "content for 2"), ...)
```

I would like to remove all elements of type `header` that are not followed by content element.

So by applying such operator result list will look like:

```
(..., Pair(2, "header"), Pair(3, "content for 2"), ...)
```

I wonder if such operator exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Francesc provides a good practical approach to solving your problem. However, if you (or anyone else) would like a solution in a more functional programming paradigm, consider this code

```
typealias CustomData = Pair<Int, String>

private fun CustomData.isHeader() = second == "header"
private fun CustomData.isContent() = !isHeader()

fun dropUnwantedHeaders(data: List<CustomData>) =
    data.asSequence()
    // add a duplicate of the last element to the list. this is an easy way in this case to deal with the problem that the map operation
    // is not the exact inverse of the zipWithNext operation
    .plusElement(data.last())
    // combine each element with the one after it since the filter predicate depends on both
    .zipWithNext()
    .filterNot { (elem, nextElem) ->
        // drop element if it is a header and the subsequent element is not content
        elem.isHeader() && !nextElem.isContent()
    }
    // undo the previous zip operation. this results in dropping the last element of the list
    .map { it.first }
    .toList()

fun main() {
    val unfilteredData = listOf(Pair(1, "header"), Pair(2, "header"), Pair(3, "content for 2"))
    val expectedResult = listOf(Pair(2, "header"), Pair(3, "content for 2"))
    assert(dropUnwantedHeaders(unfilteredData) == expectedResult)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
list.removeAll {
    val index = list.indexOf(it)
    "header" == it.second && index < list.size - 1 && "content" == list[index + 1].second 
}
```

You may need to tweak the check for "is content".

Comment: I think the last condition should be: `!headersAndContent[index + 1].second.startsWith("content")`

Comment: I suspect that will not work as expected if the list contains any duplicates.  It also won't perform well on big lists…  (The `indexOf()` turns it from being linear to quadratic in complexity.)